# How to change type of machine in an instance already created in google compute engine?

Tags: virtual-machine, instance, vps, google-compute-engine

How to change type of machine in an instance already created? Example:

n1-highcpu-4(4 vCPUs 3,6 memory ram) I want to change n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs 20 memory ram), I could explain how to do that steps should apply.

Thank you

Comment: You want to do this via the API or through the Google Compute Engine UI? If it is the first, please provide us with anything that you have tried until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change VM type after the instance has been created. But you can preserve the root disk (and any other disks you have attached to the instance), create a new instance of the desired size, and use the disks from the other VM.

** UPDATE **
It's now possible to change the machine type:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance

Comment: Hi, Fabricio thank you very much for your answer, as I do ssh console because if the disk is active in the instance can not will link to the new instance I get error.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you're saying that while the original instance is running, you cannot use the root disk which is correct. You have 2 options: 1. delete the original instance, preserving the disk, then create new instance with old disk. 2. snapshot root disk, create new disk from snapshot, and create instance using disk created from snapshot. Option #2 allows you to keep the original instance while creating a copy to a larger instance.

Comment: You should change your answer or delete it now that changing the machine type is possible, to avoid your answer getting downvoted and keep SO up to date